# n-dimensional algebra can be embedded into matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question: If A is an n-dimensional F-algebra, where F is a field, then A can be embedded into the F-subalgebra of the matrix algebra Mn(F)

Motivation: I am learning algebraic representation theory, which is a property I saw in the book, but it is not proven in the book

My attempt: assume $\{a_i\}$ be a set of bases for A, $a_ia_j=\sum_{r}b_{r}^{ij}a_{r}$. Let the image of $a_i$ in Mn(F) be $\sum_{kl}c_{kl}^{i}e_{kl}$. I want to solve $c_{kl}^{i}$ through multiplication in A, but it's too complicated.

Comment: Every element $a\in A$ defines a linear transformation $\varphi_a:A\to A$ by $\varphi_a(x)=ax$. You can show that the map $a\to\varphi_a$ is an embedding of algebras $A\to \text{End}_F(A)\cong M_n(F)$.